# Increase tableGrob column title size and cell size

Tags: r, gridextra, grob

Is there a way to increase the cell of the column name in a `tableGrob` item?

```
library(grid)
d <- head(iris, 3)
g <- tableGrob(d)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

default:

[image]

What I want to achieve (this was done in photoshop):
[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by changing the `padding` of the `colhead` within the `theme`.

eg

```
thm <- ttheme_default(colhead = 
             # first unit is the wdith, and second the height
             list(padding=unit.c(unit(4, "mm"), unit(10, "mm"))))


tableGrob(d, theme=thm)
```

To get an idea of what you can change you can view `ttheme_default()` in the terminal

Comment: Thank you @user20650. This is what I was looking for.